# Select all objects in another object area in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections, pathfinder

I explain the situation : I have objects in background and circles in front. I would like to select all objects in background that are contained in those circles area.

The pathfinder will not work, because I need to select the complete objects and not just the anchor points contained in circles area.

As in the screenshot below, I would like to delete all objects contained in this area. Do it manually is very long...

Thanks in advance for help :)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There is no internal feature in Illustrator which does what you are asking. It *may* be possible via scripting.

Comment: Contained as in fully inside, even partially inside or clipped?

Comment: Thanks Scott for your help. Joojaa, the circle and the objects are on the same layer. I want to delete all objects contained in the circle area (under the circle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a copy of this file, just in case this is not the answer you seek.

I would group the background first. Make a copy of it, paste it in place and lock it. Then, I would copy the light green circle. I would then use the light green circle to create a Clipping Mask so that you get all the knitted pattern inside the circle. You can then "paste in place" the light green circle so that it lines up on top of the clipping masked knit pattern.  You can then unlock the background and delete it if you didn't want it.

If that is a misunderstanding of your question and you are just wanting to delete the knit pattern in a circle, I would lock the circle and use the lasso to select the items, using the circle as a guide.

Hopefully one of these answers will help. :)