# Inkscape: Select all objects in another object area

Tags: inkscape

How can I select all objects that are in the area of another object?  For example, I'd like to select all stars in the red circle.

[image]

(edit) I want to select each object that its whole part is in the red circle.  The selected objects will be like this.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. As far as I know there is no such functionality in Inkscape. Might be possible using some Extension perhaps. But why are you trying to do this?  What's the ultimate goal?  If you just want stars to be inside the circle, you could group all the stars, select the group and the circle, then apply the circle as a clipping path using *Object > Clip > Set*.

Comment: At the moment your question reads a bit like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  If you can [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/152307/edit) and say what you are actually trying to achieve by doing this, then it would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you for your kind welcome message. I edited the question. My ultimate goal is to form letters (each letter is one object) into a shape as in i.stack.imgur.com/hmtBl.png  But letters can be deleted but cannot be moved.  Therefore, Text > Flow into Frame does not accomplish my goal.

Comment: Why doesn't flowing text into Frame not accomplish your goal? It works fine. What specific problem are you having with it?

Comment: A workaround which can be useful if there's hundreds of objects to be selected. It doesn't select, it deletes the unwanted. It's for Illustrator but it works as well in Inkscape.  https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/136095/using-object-to-select-other-objects-illustrator It can be used only for simple paths which do not overlap. Those paths will lose their individual colors. It's useless for texts, groups and other non-paths. It simply unites the exterior of the circle and all the shapes. When the resulted compound path is broken apart the unwanted shapes can be deleted easily.

Comment: @BillyKerr Flowing Text into Frame does not work because it move the letters.

Comment: @user287001 Thank you very much for the solution. The method help me remove unwanted objects very quickly. I union the objects and do Path > Break Apart.

Comment: Though the video is not on exactly the same topic, [this](https://youtu.be/Mue1v7GDL6I) might help you.

Comment: @The-Anonymous Thank you for the video.  The result is cool.